# can we send email notification for different role such as buyer,seller when they register their details in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, jakarta-mail

I want to send an email notification to seller and buyer when they register their profiles As I have User entities with a field of the role as I have given you a code what can do to send an email notification.

```
user class

public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 255, message = "Minimum username length: 4 characters")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role", length = 50)
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(name = "reset_token")
    private String resetToken;

    @Column(name = "confirmation_token")
    private String confirmationToken;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Item> itemList;
```

post controller

```
       @PostMapping("/register/save")
    public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute User user, HttpServletRequest request) throws MessagingException {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        emailUtil.sendEmail(user.getEmail(), "registration", "youhave sucessfully registrater in auction AS seller");


        user.setRole(request.getParameter("role"));
        String pass = user.getPassword();
        user.setPassword(b.encode(pass));
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepo.save(user);
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: What's your problem with your code? What's not working?

Comment: i need a  guidence for sending email with roles wise